# Cannot merge the following node because of null property value for 'name':

Tags: neo4j, cypher

My code:

```
LOAD CSV WITH HEADERS FROM "file:///C:/test1.csv" AS line
MERGE (n:SiteA {name: line.SiteA})
MERGE (m:SiteB {name: line.SiteB})
MERGE (n) -[:has_device_function]-> (m);
```

my error:

Cannot merge the following node because of null property value for 'name': (:SiteA {name: null})

Could you please help me ?

Answer (score 0):

ry this

> LOAD CSV WITH HEADERS FROM "file:///C:/test1.csv" AS line MATCH
> (n:SiteA {name: line.SiteA}) where n.name is not null MATCH (m:SiteB
> {name: line.SiteB}) where m.name is not null MERGE (n)
> -[:has_device_function]-> (m);

Two things to notice: filtering out nulls and using MATCH rather than merge in the initial extraction of the nodes for the new relationship.

Answer (score 0):

In order to easily avoid this kind of problem I usually pass a default value on null items for my CSV (usually DELETE_ME_PLEASE). Then I'll just match and delete nodes with this.

Answer (score 0):

First, just to be sure: this means that there are rows in your CSV that have an empty name column.

That said, you can remove lines from the CSV before continuing your query:

```
LOAD CSV WITH HEADERS FROM "file:///C:/test1.csv" AS line
WITH line WHERE line.name IS NOT NULL
MERGE (n:SiteA {name: line.SiteA})
MERGE (m:SiteB {name: line.SiteB})
MERGE (n) -[:has_device_function]-> (m);
```

Answer (score -3):

Csv need coma only and that's work ...

Comment: Please add further details to expand on your answer, such as working code or documentation citations.